# How to use this in prototype function with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to migrate some `JavaScript` functionality to `OOP JavaScript` like this:

```
function Test(parameters) {

    this.containerID = parameters['containerID'];
    ....
    this.navNext = $('#' + this.containerID + ' #test');
    ...
}

Test.prototype = {
    constructor: Test,
    ...
    init: function () {
        ...
        this.navNext.on('click', function (event) {
            ...
            this.showNext(); //here is the issue
        });
       ...
    },
    showNext: function () {
        ...
    }  
};
```

Then I am instantiating new instance like follows:

```
test = new Test({'containerID':'test_id'});
test.init();
```

But when I click on the "next button" or (`$('#test_id '#test'` element) I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showNext is not defined
```

I guess in the `on` jQuery function `this.showNext()` is pointing to selected element `showNext()` function, not my prototype function.

Could anyone give me an advice how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an event handler,`this` refers to the element that received the event. You can instead make an outer reference to the desired `this`.

```
var that = this;

this.navNext.on('click', function (event) {
    ...
    that.showNext();
});
```

---

Or use `Function.prototype.bind()`, which can be shimmed in older browsers.

```
this.navNext.on('click', function (event) {
    ...
    this.showNext();
}.bind(this));
```

---

Or `$proxy`.

```
this.navNext.on('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
    ...
    this.showNext();
}, this));
```

---

Or pass the object as event data.

```
this.navNext.on('click', this, function (event) {
    ...
    event.data.showNext();
});
```

---

Note that in the versions that alter `this`, you can still get a reference to the element via `event.currentTarget`. Or just use the `event.data` version, and `this` will still be the element.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what `this` is

```
this.navNext.on('click', function (event) {
    console.log(this);
    this.showNext(); //here is the issue
});
```

When you look at it in the log, you will see that "this" is the element you clicked on.

The scope is wrong, but you can fix it with [jQuery's proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
this.navNext.on('click', $.proxy(this.showNext,this));
```

or you can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.navNext.on('click', this.showNext.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just save a reference to the object in the `on('click'` handler:

```
   var thisRef = this;
    this.navNext.on('click', function (event) {
        ...
        thisRef.showNext(); //here is the issue
    });
```